# Custom 405 Error Message via Htaccess Doesn't show When Sending PHP Header

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers, http-status-code-405

I prevent direct access to a the following file by returning a 405, unless the user submitted a form, with this code:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed"); 
    exit(); } else {

if(isset($_POST['a'])){

    switch ($_POST['a']) {

    case "1":
        $var = "hey";
        break;

    case "2":
        $var = "now";
        break;

    default:
        $var = "other";
    }
  }
}
?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
something
</body>
</html>
```

Since Chrome and FF display a blank page rather than en error (even though they would display a 404 and not a blank page in case I type a wrong URL, so I'm not sure how this works), I want to create a custom 405 message, So I've added this line to my .htaccess:

`ErrorDocument 405 /custom-msg.php`

And yet, I still get a blank page rather than the custom message.
what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache isn't set up to action error documents for PHP set status codes. Similarly to your 404 issue, try:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed"); 
include 'custom-msg.php';
exit(); }
```

Comment: ignore the previous comment, let me check this again:)

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd see this on IE as well, but the include only works on FF/Chrome, now way to make this uniform?

Comment: How big is your custom-msg.php file? IE only displays the response if it's longer than 512 bytes for some reason :) x